# Transform time span strings to seconds in real number form

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, time, duration

i have a panda with strings in the timespan format DD.hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn .Looking for way to convert it into seconds that can be stored as real numbers.
The dataframe:

```
duration {'13:11:21.2600000','12.18:52:17.0640000','12.18:52:17.0640000','4.07:28:42.7160000','4.09:30:34.1700000'}
```

I tried using :

```py
for dur in duration:
    secs= dur.total_seconds()
    rlist.append(secs)
```

But got the following error:

> AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Was successfully using this inefficient way using regex:

```py
df=df.astype(str)
daySearch="\.\d\d:"
sep='.'
for i in duration:
    if re.search(daySearch,i):
       day,dur,micros=i.split('.')
       h, m, s = dur.split(':')
       secs_int=(int(day) * 86400) + (int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s))
       secs=str(secs_int)+sep+micros
       print(secs)
    else:
        dur, micros = i.split('.')
        h, m, s = dur.split(':')
        secs_int = int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)
        secs = str(secs_int) + sep + micros
        print(secs)
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the string to date time instance using strptime

```
datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
```

Then convert to total seconds w.r.t. some reference time.

```
(dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Got the the following error:                                                                               ValueError: time data '13:11:21.2600000' does not match format '%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'  will converting it to datetime

Comment: Format string doesn't match. You should use a matching format string. %H:%M:%:S.%f